# Running two mutually exclusive rsync on the same folder

Tags: rsync

I have files stored on two servers, `A` and `B`. I'd like to copy both into the same directory tree on server `C`. Is it safe to run both of these commands at once if `A` and `B` have the same folder structure, but the files stored in those folders have no collisions?

**On `A`**:

```
$ rsync -a /folder/ C:/folder
```

**On `B`**:

```
$ rsync -a /folder/ C:/folder
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be ok if there are no collisions, but only as-is (i.e. something like the --delete flag would be a bad thing :))

If you wanted to check and be sure, you could use the -v and -n options to see what would happen without actually doing it, e.g.:
rsync -avn /folder/ C:/folder

Comment: If file names collide, the system will react badly.  Safer would be t o copy to C:/folder/A and C:/folder/B and modify the code to search both directories.